# g++ and gcc behave differently on pthread_cleanup_push/pop

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, pthreads

This is my code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void cleanup(void *arg) {
    printf("cleanup: %s\n", (const char*)arg);
}

void *thr_fn1(void *arg) {
    printf("thread 1 strat\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void*)"thread 1 first handler");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void*)"thread 1 first handler");

    if(arg)
        return (void*)1;

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return (void*)1;
}

void *thr_fn2(void *arg) {
    printf("thread 2 strat\n");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void*)"thread 2 first handler");
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void*)"thread 2 first handler");

    if(arg)
        return (void*)2;

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return (void*)2;
}

int main() {
    int err;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    void *tret;

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thr_fn1, (void*)1);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thr_fn2, (void*)1);

    pthread_join(tid1, &tret);
    printf("pthread 1 exit code %ld\n", tret);
    pthread_join(tid2, &tret);
    printf("pthread 2 exit code %ld\n", tret);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I run it using `gcc` and `g++`

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ ./main
thread 2 strat
thread 1 strat
pthread 1 exit code 1
pthread 2 exit code 2
$ g++ main.c -o main
$ ./main
thread 1 strat
cleanup: thread 1 first handler
cleanup: thread 1 first handler
thread 2 strat
cleanup: thread 2 first handler
cleanup: thread 2 first handler
pthread 1 exit code 1
pthread 2 exit code 2
$
```

1. Why they behave differently?
2. Any other functions behave like this?
3. I found the implementations of `gcc` and `g++` are different. So which one is a better implementation?

Comment: Neither is correct because you don't link with `-pthread`.

Comment: If you want to write C++, you don't need to use `pthread_*` functions directly. You can use the standard libraries `std::thread` instead, which has a proper C++ interface.

Comment: Also: "_The effect of the use of return, break, continue, and goto to prematurely leave a code block described by a pair of pthread_cleanup_push() and pthread_cleanup_pop() functions calls is undefined._" (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html)

Comment: Your question looks like a pure "C" one, "C++". These are seperate languages, pick only one in your tags. As said in C++ we (should) use threads that are build into the language now.

Answer (score 5):

> On Linux, the `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` functions are implemented as macros that expand to text containing `{` and `}`, respectively.

```
#  define pthread_cleanup_push(routine, arg) \
  do {                                       \
    __pthread_cleanup_class __clframe (routine, arg)
```

If compiled with g++, `__pthread_cleanup_class` is a C++ class:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
/* Class to handle cancellation handler invocation.  */
class __pthread_cleanup_class
{
  void (*__cancel_routine) (void *);
  void *__cancel_arg;
  int __do_it;
  int __cancel_type;

 public:
  __pthread_cleanup_class (void (*__fct) (void *), void *__arg)
    : __cancel_routine (__fct), __cancel_arg (__arg), __do_it (1) { }
  ~__pthread_cleanup_class () { if (__do_it) __cancel_routine (__cancel_arg); }
  void __setdoit (int __newval) { __do_it = __newval; }
  void __defer () { pthread_setcanceltype (PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED,
                                           &__cancel_type); }
  void __restore () const { pthread_setcanceltype (__cancel_type, 0); }
};
```

It behaves like any class, its destructor runs on scope end.

In C, using gcc, cleanup handlers require `pthread_exit()`, but your code does `return`.

> 2. When a thread terminates by calling [`pthread_exit(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html), all clean-up handlers are executed as described in the preceding point.  **(Clean-up handlers are not called if the thread terminates by performing a return from the thread start function.)**

Comment: So glibc + C++ is actually buggy here.  The spec says that cleanup handlers are not run when a thread terminates by `return`ing from the initial call to the start function, but in the `g++`-built version of the program, they are.